# Using gettext results in periods changed with commas

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, gettext

I am using Codeigniter, and did implement gettext/.po internationalization by making a helper, and the corresponding .po/.mo files.

Each string that is meant to be replaced looks like this: `_('some text here');`

But when after implementing this successfully, I noticed that PHP calculations which resulted in numbers like 100.98 etc, were changed with 100,98. Also, the period is changed with a comma.

For example, this calculation usually results in a number like 1037.67:

```
    <?php
      // Space total
      $space_total = $space_info[0]->space_total;

      // Prepare space used
      $space_used = $space[0]->media_size / 1000000;
      $space_used = round($space_used, 1);

      // Prepare progressbar
      $percent = $space_used / $space_total * 100;

    ?>
```

But when after implementing gettext it results in 1037,67. I have troubleshooted if there is other factors that is causing this, but it happens only when I run the gettext language init function inside the helper.

Here is the helper:

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function set_translation_language($language){
  $lang_path = FCPATH.APPPATH.'language/locales';
  putenv('LANG='.$language.'.UTF-8');
  setlocale(LC_ALL, $language.'.UTF-8');
  bindtextdomain('lang', $lang_path);
  textdomain('lang');
}
```

Which is called with this as an example:

```
set_translation_language('en_US');
```

Do someone have a explanation to this?

Comment: Do somebody have an explanation or solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using LC_ALL in your call to setlocale(). LC_ALL not only includes text but also string sorting, number formatting, date formatting and more.

You should use LC_MESSAGES for translating text. You should use LC_NUMERIC only when outputting numeric data that you wish to be formatted in the local format.

set_translation_language($language) should use setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $language.'.UTF-8');

When you want a number outputting you should do

```
$percent = $space_used / $space_total * 100;
$current_locale = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 0);    // Get the current locale
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, $language.'.UTF-8);
print $percent;
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, $current_locale);
```